# Which is the difference between "interesting things of" vs interesting things about"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it wrong to say:

> One of the most interesting things **of** my job...

instead of

> One of the most interesting things **about** my job...

And to be broad, when should the writer use "about" instead of "of" to express origin?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to decide whether something is OK to say or perhaps not necessarily so, try to imagine how else, in some other context you would use similar phrases and what they'd sound like, what the meaning would be.

> One of the most interesting things of my job...

Try to split it into parts and use each part separately.  What is "a thing of my job"?  How would you answer that question?  Is it even a valid question?  Does your job *consist **of** things*?  The preposition "***of***" is used in this case to indicate an integral part, a characteristic, a trait.

Now, the question

> One of the most interesting things **about** my job...

points to "things" that *aren't* an integral part of the job, but "*about*" it, things with which "*my job*" interacts closely.

Another way to understand the sentence with the "*about*" preposition is that you want to describe your job using some aspects that reflect some specific features:

> Here are a few stories **about** my job.
>   Let me tell you **about** my job...

And then you can simply convert "stories"/"tales" and call them "things".  Those are not necessarily real ***things***.  They are just objects of interest.  We just use that word:

> Here is the ***thing***; I am afraid that...
>   Don't worry about a ***thing***!
>   ***Things*** don't look good...

So, if you treat "thing" in those expressions as "stories" or "tales" or "fables", then it *might* be OK to use "***of***", but it's a stretch, and you're better off just saying

> One of the most interesting stories of my job...

and even then, it's better to use "about" or "from".

---

I can think of one possibility in which "of" is perfectly OK:

> One of the most interesting ***aspects*** *of* my job...

In other words, instead of "things" you need to use something that *belongs* to your job, or *defines* it.

Comment: I think you've given the right answer, but I also think it can be **very** difficult to pick the right prepostion, especially between _of_ and _about_. There even contexts where maybe either one would work. For example: _We must convince them of/about the severity of the problem_.

Comment: "Convince somebody *about* something", really?  I don't think I ever heard it used like that.

Comment: _Perhaps the most difficult group to convince about project ownership will be your own staff_ (Hackos 2007). _Agencies with knowledge about old technologies can sometimes be difficult to convince about the new alternatives_ (Gil-Garcia 2012). _Those who are difficult to convince about anything are likely to react to all new ideas in a negative manner_ (Prosser 2010). _Perhaps the two most difficult constituencies to convince about anything new are teachers and parents._ (Gaertner 2011). _The first person you need to convince about the importance of delegation is you_ (Infinite Ideas 2012).

Comment: I am sure if I ask Google about it, there will be plenty... 33k results for "thnig" don't make it the correct spelling.

Comment: VictorB: All of those examples were from published books.